# Flow control, implementation replace method List

Tags: java, iterator, nullpointerexception

Directly from [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html]

```
public static <E> void replace(List<E> list, E val, E newVal) {
    for (ListIterator<E> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if (val == null ? it.next() == null : val.equals(it.next()))
            it.set(newVal); }
```

> The only bit of trickiness in this example is the equality test
>   between val and it.next. You need to special-case a val value of null
>   to prevent a NullPointerException.

I am wondering why the we need to special-case a val value of null to prevent a NullPointerException. I might understand that we have to safe code to prevent a NullPointerException however that line of code

```
if (val == null ? it.next() == null : val.equals(it.next()))
```

is not related to the collection iteration, but instead the val parameter is specified only in the parameters method.

Thanks in advance for any clarification with the above mentioned.

Comment: I'm surprised that there's not an explicit check for `null` for the `list` parameter too...

Comment: @mre That's an excellent comment! The reason for not having to null-check elements of the list is that the contract of `Object`'s `equals` method explicitly allows passing `null` arguments (take a look at the javadoc for other requirements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reading of what is going on here is absolutely right: the "special case" that they are talking about is related to null-checking a parameter, not to the iteration of the list.

In fact, you could move the `if` statement *outside* the loop for a slightly more efficient but less readable solution:

```
if (val != null) {
    for (ListIterator<E> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if (val.equals(it.next()))
            it.set(newVal);
} else {
    for (ListIterator<E> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if (it.next() == null)
            it.set(newVal);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The test encapsulates two distinct rules for locating `val` in `list`:

1. if `val` is `null`, then the list element must be `null` for there to be a match (recall that lists can contain `null` values)
2. if `val` is not `null`, then `val` must equal (using `.equals()`) the list element for there to be a match

The `NullPointerException` would arise if you tried to evaluate `val.equals(list.next())` when `val` was `null`.

The method could have been written like this:

```
public static <E> void replace(List<E> list, E val, E newVal) {
    if (val == null) {
        for (ListIterator<E> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )
            if (it.next() == null)
                it.set(newVal);
    } else {
        for (ListIterator<E> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )
            if (val.equals(it.next()))
                it.set(newVal);
    }
}
```